# Angular Material - Shared popups* styling problem

Tags: angular, angular-material, popup

is there any chance how to set where will be popup and not only popups but any element which is dynamically created and appended at the very and of DOM?

The default behavior is to append popup at the very end of the DOM. This element will be shared for all components who need it ( for example drag & drop list is placed where it should be... but its dragging item is placed at the very end of the DOM )

This is ok until your task is to make 5 variations of drag & drop lists with different styles... This sharing element ( in this case the dragging item ) means the same styles of this element for everyone. If I change it, I will change it for everyone. There is no way how to write specific CSS selector because this element doesn't belong to anyone.

I had the same problem with kendo controls but they had a solution. There was a simple setting where you can attach this popup to the parent component.

```
 this.datePickerTo.kendoComponent.popupSettings = {
  appendTo: 'component'
};
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem for Angular Material ? I can't find any solution. Thank you

Comment: How are you dynamically creating components are you using angular `ComponentFactoryResolver` ??

Comment: Angular Material does it by itself. I just use their components.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the angular material popup API, you can find a `viewContainerRef` option in the `MatDialogConfig` Class, so in order to get your popups inside a host component you can try passing the host view container ref in the open method.

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api

Here's a quick example of how you can implement that solution:

```
@ViewChild('hostComponent') hostComponent;

// You basically have this in a component method
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      viewContainerRef: this.hostComponent.viewContainerRef
});
```

And in your component template you will need to mark you view childs like this:

```
<ng-template host-component></ng-template>
```

Here's a good reading on manipulating components dynamically:

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Hello Mehdi, your answer was the biggest hope of today :D ... but after an hour I didn't find any way how to adapt your solution for drag and drop component. https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api - maybe i am blind but there is nothing that can fix my problem ( there is something like ( element: ElementRef ) but its not solution.